# Pandas bar plot with binned range

Tags: python, pandas, histogram, bar-chart

Is there a way to create a bar plot from continuous data binned into predefined intervals? For example,

```
In[1]: df
Out[1]: 
0      0.729630
1      0.699620
2      0.710526
3      0.000000
4      0.831325
5      0.945312
6      0.665428
7      0.871845
8      0.848148
9      0.262500
10     0.694030
11     0.503759
12     0.985437
13     0.576271
14     0.819742
15     0.957627
16     0.814394
17     0.944649
18     0.911111
19     0.113333
20     0.585821
21     0.930131
22     0.347222
23     0.000000
24     0.987805
25     0.950570
26     0.341317
27     0.192771
28     0.320988
29     0.513834

231    0.342541
232    0.866279
233    0.900000
234    0.615385
235    0.880597
236    0.620690
237    0.984375
238    0.171429
239    0.792683
240    0.344828
241    0.288889
242    0.961686
243    0.094402
244    0.960526
245    1.000000
246    0.166667
247    0.373494
248    0.000000
249    0.839416
250    0.862745
251    0.589873
252    0.983871
253    0.751938
254    0.000000
255    0.594937
256    0.259615
257    0.459916
258    0.935065
259    0.969231
260    0.755814
```

and instead of a simple histogram:

```
df.hist()
```

[image: usual histogram of df]

I need to create a bar plot, where each bar will count a number of instances within a predefined range. 
For example, the following plot should have three bars with the number of points which fall into: [0 0.35], [0.35 0.7] [0.7 1.0]

**EDIT**

Many thanks for your answers. Another question, how to order bins?
For example, I get the following result:

```
In[349]: out.value_counts()
Out[349]:  
[0, 0.001]      104
(0.001, 0.1]     61
(0.1, 0.2]       32
(0.2, 0.3]       20
(0.3, 0.4]       18
(0.7, 0.8]        6
(0.4, 0.5]        6
(0.5, 0.6]        5
(0.6, 0.7]        4
(0.9, 1]          3
(0.8, 0.9]        2
(1, 1.001]        0
```

as you can see, the last three bins are not ordered. How to sort the data frame based on 'categories' or my bins?

**EDIT 2**

Just found how to solve it, simply with 'reindex()':

```
In[355]: out.value_counts().reindex(out.cat.categories)
Out[355]: 
[0, 0.001]      104
(0.001, 0.1]     61
(0.1, 0.2]       32
(0.2, 0.3]       20
(0.3, 0.4]       18
(0.4, 0.5]        6
(0.5, 0.6]        5
(0.6, 0.7]        4
(0.7, 0.8]        6
(0.8, 0.9]        2
(0.9, 1]          3
(1, 1.001]        0
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can make use of [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) to partition the values into bins corresponding to each interval and then take each interval's total counts using [`pd.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Plot a bar graph later, additionally replace the X-axis tick labels with the category name to which that particular tick belongs.

```
out = pd.cut(s, bins=[0, 0.35, 0.7, 1], include_lowest=True)
ax = out.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4))
ax.set_xticklabels([c[1:-1].replace(","," to") for c in out.cat.categories])
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you want the Y-axis to be displayed as relative percentages, normalize the frequency counts and multiply that result with 100.

```
out = pd.cut(s, bins=[0, 0.35, 0.7, 1], include_lowest=True)
out_norm = out.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True).mul(100)
ax = out_norm.plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4))
ax.set_xticklabels([c[1:-1].replace(","," to") for c in out.cat.categories])
plt.ylabel("pct")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: and if I need to normalise the plot? (vertical axis should be percentage and not the frequency. Similar to 'normed=True' in .hist()

Comment: I get TypeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object is not subscriptable when trying to change the tick labels

Comment: @famargar: If you're on versions >= 0.20.0, the old way of slicing would not work as it has now become an `IntervalIndex` which has it's own dtype and doesn't support indexing. Hence, the preferred way of doing the same would be to make use of the attributes (left/right) to define the interval of X-axis tick labels.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A bit change to above code -> `str(c)[1:-1].replace(...)`

Answer (score 29):

You may consider using matplotlib to plot the histogram. Unlike pandas' `hist` function, `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` accepts an array as input for the bins.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = np.random.rand(120)
df = pd.DataFrame({"x":x})

bins= [0,0.35,0.7,1]
plt.hist(df.values, bins=bins, edgecolor="k")
plt.xticks(bins)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This method here it's less verbose and should be placed as the main answer.

Comment: Current pandas 1.3.3 and probably older pandas.hist() does accept a bin sequence:

(...)If bins is a sequence, gives bin edges, including left edge of first bin and right edge of last bin. In this case, bins is returned unmodified.

Comment: Possibly a noob question: isn't the default mode in pandas using mathplotlib?

Comment: Note that with this method, the bins width may be visually different for each bins.

Answer (score 18):

You can use pd.cut

```
bins = [0,0.35,0.7,1]
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['val'], bins=bins)).val.count()
df.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]