# Indexing error in plot for pandas version >= 0.20

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006004/5016028), as it does exactly what I want. I paste it here for the completeness of my question:

```
out = pd.cut(s, bins=[0, 0.35, 0.7, 1], include_lowest=True)
out_norm = out.value_counts(sort=False, normalize=True).mul(100)
ax = out_norm.plot.bar(rot=0, color="b", figsize=(6,4))
ax.set_xticklabels([c[1:-1].replace(","," to") for c in out.cat.categories])
plt.ylabel("pct")
plt.show()
```

I get an error pointing at the `ax.set_xticklabels` line, stating that:

```
TypeError: 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object is not subscriptable.
```

I understand this has been changed after pandas version `0.20`. How can I modify that line to do the same thing but avoid the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the Interval object subscriptable by calling `str()` on it:

```
ax.set_xticklabels([str(c)[1:-1].replace(","," to") for c in out.cat.categories])
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it.