# how to draw categorized bar chart from data frame in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart

I have a data frame which has the average amount of delay for each person. a sample of my data comes in the following:

```
    personId    avg_Time(minutes)   
0   1           -18
1   2           3
2   3           5
```

I would like to show my data with a bar-chart and categorized the data such as the following:
[image]

so it shows how many persons have a delay between 0 to 10 minutes,
and how many people have a delay between 10 to 20 and so on...

I want to know how I can draw such a figure based on my data.
Thank you for your help

Comment: This will probably help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43006004/13719353

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a histogram of `avg_Time` with specified bins:

```
df['avg_Time(minutes)'].hist(bins=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
```